# Cannot remove code modules from a destination workbook through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am running an Excel 2010 macro that opens another workbook and removes a few code modules (a form and a BAS module). After that it re-imports them as an updated version. This is the code:

```
For Each x In destination_wb.VBProject.VBComponents
  If LCase(x.Name) Like LCase("frmCCLogin*") Or _
      LCase(x.Name) Like LCase("modCQ_test*") Then
  destination_wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove (x)
Next
```

I have no problem with the import but the remove process doesn't always work as expected. For some reason the BAS (modCQ_test.bas) module is not always removed. As a result, when I re-import, a new duplicated module is created ending with a "1" (i.e. modCQ_test1.bas). 
I could see that many people experienced the same problem however, none of the proposed solutions worked for me. Not sure why this is happening?
Please advise.

Comment: have you tried to set a `Debug.Print` for the true/false to output each name it finds? also, you may change the `LCase(x.Name) Like LCase("frmCCLogin*")` to `Left(LCase(x.Name), 10) = "frmcclogin"` (also for the other check)

Comment: I changed the posting title to be more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the exact name of the module, you can write something like:

```
Public Sub RemoveComponent(ByVal Book As Workbook, ByVal Name As String)

On Error Resume Next
With Book.VBProject.VBComponents
    Call .Remove(.Item(Name))
End With

End Sub
```

If you're stuck with wildcard matching (i.e. SomeName*) you could iterate the VBComponents collection and cache the names into a collection or array or whatever and call the function above for each name matched.

Additionally, if you wish to enumerate the VBComponents collection and remove like your code sample, I recommend that you go in the reverse order.

So something like:

```
Public Sub RemoveComponent1(ByVal Book As Workbook, ByVal NameSearch As String)

Dim oCompS As VBComponents
Dim oComp As VBComponent
Dim i As Integer

Set oCompS = Book.VBProject.VBComponents
For i = oCompS.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oComp = oCompS(i)
    If oComp.Name Like NameSearch Then Call oCompS.Remove(oComp)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it's the problem of "cutting the branch you sit on", which sometimes can be resolved by iterating backwards. Generally, you cannot safely use For Each on a Collection and then modify that Collection inside the loop. The reason is that the next iteration sees fewer elements in the Collection, screwing up internal counters. That way, you might miss subsequent entries.

Comment: thank you PaulG and Oliver, I followed your suggestion and iterate in reverse order. However the problem seems to be related to using the LIKE function, I also modified the code to look for an exact name match and it worked! Very strange, why LIKE + LCASE could not identify the module name?

Comment: UPDATE: it is happening again sporadically. For example, it works 1-2 times but the 3-rd time it fails. A duplicated module is added to the workbook.

Comment: Try to see if you can trap any error. So at the bottom of the RemoveComponent function put something like: If Not Err.Number = 0 then Stop. Then test that baby to see if you can get some info on the Error.

Comment: Hhhmm that's strange. If you remove the module manually and compile, do you get any errors in the compilation? i.e. does anything else in your code rely on any functions/routines in the module you are removing? Also, instead of removing the module you could try keeping the module but replacing the code with the new code instead...

Comment: OK, It seems resolved now. I just added the following line of code:     destination_wb.Windows(1).Visible = False just before starting iterating through the destination workbook modules. My understanding is that some procedure from the code module I was trying to remove has been executing in Workbook_Open event and as a result, this specific module was "locked" and could not be removed. Not sure though if it's the case but I tried already many times and the remove process works perfectly,

Comment: Many thanks to everybody that took the time to help me resolving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is resolved. This simple line of code that hides the destination workbook, fixed the duplication issue in my case:

```
destination_wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

After this you can remove, then add the components. No duplication will occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced exactly the same phenomenon and it drove me mad for weeks already.
I do check whether the Code Module had definitely been removed directly after the removal and although it had vanished from the VBE's Project View, it still exists and consequently the subsequent import creates a Code Module named xxx1.
Any of the hints given proved not to be reliable on the long run and thus are nothing but guesses. Since the phenomenon is unpredictable as mentioned you never can really tell what did the trick.

Comment: Problem is resolved. This simple line of code that hides the destination workbook fixed the duplication issue in my case:      destination_wb.Windows(1).Visible = False

Comment: Please try it and post a comment if it solves your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

As time (some years) has passed I do now have an answer for the phenomenon and a solid and stable solution.

1. In order not to "cut off the branch you sit on" one will have to envoke another Workbook/VB-Project for deleting and re-importing a Component.
2. Even another VB-Project performing the task will have to consider that the Component is definitely removed when the code which removed it has "finished".

Conclusion: Rename, Remove, Import, all performed by a VB-Project invoked via "Run ...."  will do the trick.